# Git is stuck on clone after adding ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

yesterday I set up my ssh key for github, I added the key and tried to pull a repo using ssh. But git is stuck in the "Cloning into" phase and I have to cancel the request because nothing happens.

I also followed the instructions on the github site to check my ssh keys and after executing `ssh -T git@github.com` I'm getting a connection timeout.

Lastly I'd like to mention that I'm using a proxy and that I've configured my environment to use this proxy and I also set the proxy on the config file for git but the issue still remains.

Right now I don't know if this issue comes from the proxy that I'm using or from the ssh configuration. I tried setting my proxy in the ssh config file but it also didn't work.

This is the command I used to set up my proxy with git, where proxyIpAddress is the address the company is using.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyIpAddress:8080
```

I also set up an https proxy for git but I don't know if it is correct:

```
git config --global https.proxy https://proxyIpAddress:8080
```

This is the output from the terminal, it doesn't say much though:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.253.113 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you paste the exact commands you've tried along with the error messages?

Comment: @22kar edited my question